# Leaflet: iterate through data for custom markers

Tags: loops, csv, leaflet, marker

I need your help with custom markers in Leaflet. I need custom markers that correspond with the data entries. Here is a data SAMPLE `csv` that looks like this:

| result | display_na | lat | long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AV | 14, Amsterdamer Straße, Leopoldkiez, Wedding, Mitte, Berlin, 13347, Deutschland | 13.3574034 | 52.5517197 |
| VK | Seestraße, Wedding, Mitte, Berlin, 13351, Deutschland | 52.541301 | 13.3341968 |

This is my code by now

```
// create 3 types of markers in 3 colors

var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
  options: {
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  },
});

// Read markers data from data.csv
$.get("./data.csv", function (csvString) {
  // Use PapaParse to convert string to array of objects
  var data = Papa.parse(csvString, { header: true, dynamicTyping: true }).data;

  var greenIcon = new LeafIcon({ iconUrl: "greeb.png" }),
    yellowIcon = new LeafIcon({ iconUrl: "yellow.png" }),
    redIcon = new LeafIcon({ iconUrl: "red.png" });

  // For each row in data, create a marker and add it to the map
  // For each row, columns `Latitude`, `Longitude`, and `Title` are required
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];

    var marker = L.marker([row.lat, row.long], {
      opacity: 1,
    }).bindPopup(row.display_na);

    L.marker([row.lat, row.long])
      .addTo(map)
      .bindPopup(row.display_na)
      .openPopup();
  }
});
```

It's not working. Can you tell me where my failure lies? I have 3 types of markers

- greenIcon
- yellowIcon
- redIcon

The color of the marker corresponds with the row `result`. If the result value in the `csv` is `AV` then the marker should be `greenIcon`. That's the idea.

Than you for, looking forward to your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. First you need a ternary or an if statement to check csv's result value as you mention when instantiating a marker. It accepts an object which has some options including icon key. Using that you can define a different icon apart from the predefined

```
for (var i in data) {
          var row = data[i];

     const marker = L.marker([row.lat, row.long], {
        icon: row.result === "AV" ? greenIcon : blueIcon
     })
     .addTo(map)
     .bindPopup(row.display_na)
     .openPopup();
 }
```

Moreover your csv should be in the form of:

```
result,display_na,lat,long
AV,14 Amsterdamer Straße Leopoldkiez Wedding Mitte Berlin 13347 Deutschland,52.5517197,13.3574034
VK,Seestraße Wedding Mitte Berlin 13351 Deutschland,52.541301,13.3341968
```

You need to have commas only when separating each column values otherwise it is considered a different column value.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-iterate-through-data-for-custom-markers-d7j41?file=/data.csv:0-197)